# How to handle css issue in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am trying to disable the button using css but i could not do it.
I have used host css to fill the color so i can not override the previous color.
 If you see my **stackblitz** you can easily understand. 
I have tried disabled `Save 1` and `Save 3` buttons, but i could not change disabled look the buttons.
Anyone can find the issue please resolve it.

Stackblitz link [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-z1vreh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Code:**

```
<myngbutton colorfil="filled" [disabled]="disabled1" (onClick)="alertMsg()">Save 1</myngbutton>
```

Comment: `css` cannot disable buttons, for that matter, any DOM element. `disabled` is a `attribute`/`property` and must be done using javascript or directly in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put wrong *syntax* for **disabled** and **click**.
Try this, I have run on your ***Stackblitz*** and it is running fine:
`<myngbutton colorfil="filled" [class.disabled]="disabled1" (click)="alertMsg()">Save 1</myngbutton>`

Hope your problem get solved!

Comment: This way he will not be able to add the `disabled` attribute to the `<button>` itself, because the value of the input `disabled` within the `myngbutton` component will always be true (as it is the default).

Comment: I have added and run the same it is working fine, what you mean by this?

Comment: Following your solution, if you click on any button, they are all disabled, even though only the first and last have 'visually' disabled appearance.

Comment: So, you can follow @iamrajshah approach, but keep the [disabled] attribute:

`<myngbutton colorfil="filled" [class.disabled]="disabled1" 
 [disabled]="disabled1" (click)="alertMsg()">Save 1</myngbutton>`

Comment: from question he wants to disable button 1 & 3 while button 2 should alert the message box. It is working fine as in .ts he had mention flag for each button.

Comment: Why you are adding one more attribute, I don't understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187253/discussion-between-miguel-leite-and-iamrajshah).

Comment: @RojaS If you have got answer, do upvote and accept it so question will get close.

Comment: @iamrajshah: Can i use click  instead of onClick..  Like <myngbutton colorfil="filled" [disabled]="disabled2" (onclick)="alertMsg()">Save 1</myngbutton>

Comment: (onClick) is not an right syntax, instead use (click)

Comment: @RojaS what are you saying?? Listen I think stackblitz not saving my changes and override with previous one. You can just put 
**<myngbutton colorfil="filled" [disabled]="disabled2" (click)="alertMsg()">Save 2</myngbutton>**  and try to run. It is running on my end

Comment: @iamrajshah    As per your idea when disabled condition alert is working..pls check it...I want alert should work on button enable condition.

Comment: @RojaS on disabling how can button will able to click?

Comment: @iamrajshah:No need click option on disable condition..click should work on only button enable condition  Example : http://jsfiddle.net/wbg12cy7/

Comment: Yes it is working as expected. What is your concern right now?

Comment: @iamrajshah:  Can you answer this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519145/how-to-set-css-margin-for-my-ng-content-all-child-html-elements

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `disabled` input property on your myngbutton component, and adding it as an attribute for the actual `<button>` HTML element, you can just simply switch your CSS for disabled buttons to be:

```
.btn[disabled] {
    background-color: #cccccc !important;
    color:#cccccc !important;;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc !important;
}
```

Comment: No need of this overhead, changing a sytax will work!

Comment: Check my answer to your solution above.

Comment: As we are using angular we don't have to add extra style to it, disabled will work if we write `[class.disabled]`

Comment: Yes..No need class.disabled

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you have missed one of the inputs from your parent i.e type.

Try passing `[type]="'button'"` in **app.component.html**