# How to set css margin for my ng-content all child html elements?

Tags: angular6, angular7

[image: This is what you want?]
I need margin top,bottom,left,right of my all html components inside the ng-content.How to write the css for that? I tried but not working.Please help me to resolve this issue.

app.component.html:

```
 <div class="wrapper"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

app.component.css:

```
  .wrapper{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#ccc;
  height:60px;
  padding:10px;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%; 
  }
 .wrapper:: ng-deep <ng-content>{
  margin:5px 8px 4px 2px;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;

  }
```

Comment: Where you have put this? I mean in which file?

Comment: @iamrajshah: Edited my question..pls check it.

Comment: can you upload code on stackblitz or jsfiddle that will help me to understand better

Comment: @iamrajshah:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-l7ejfl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Can you tell me how and what is you looking for ? ng-content is not there in angulr 2 onwards. Can you draw on a page what you want so that I can help u in this?

Comment: @iamrajshah: ngcontent also there in angular upto 7. I want to set margin to all the elements inside of ng-content. from my stackblitz content component is a global component. i am passing buttons inside the content component. i will pass sometimes radio,checkbox and other html elements. so i want to set margin to all the html elements inside the ng-content.

Comment: What is problem now??

Comment: I could not set margin to html elements of ng-content. How to set?

Comment: So i have edited question and add one image, let me know is this what you want?

Comment: @iamrajshah: Yes..You understood correctly

Comment: I have posted answer

Answer (score 0):

app.component.html

```
 <div class="wrapper">

 <button class="left">Left</button> 
 <button class="right">Right</button>

</div>
```

app.component.css

```
.left{
  float:left;
}

.right{
  float:right;
}


.center{
   text-align: center; 
}


 .wrapper{
  margin:15px 8px 4px 2px;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%; 
  height:60px;

}
```

You can add your HTML content inside `<div class="wrapper"></div>`.
I hope you found this useful!!

**EDIT**
Change class to wrapper.

Comment: Do not use class for that. i need without class from app.component.css. can you edit wrapper css?

Comment: You have used wrapper in question, then why you are asking not to give in answer?? I am still not getting you

Comment: My requirement is do not use class.We want to use only one class that is wrapper then we can write css for ng-content directive

Comment: See @Feroz Ahmed answer..same like that but that is not working

Comment: I think now you understood

Comment: This css is not working .wrapper >  *
 {
    margin: 12px 10px 8px 6px; 
 }

Comment: Not working rajshah:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-hlgrn1?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this is not possible due to component's encapsulation. When `app.component.scss` is applied to its DOM, there isn't content inside `ng-content`. Event further, styles applies to `ng-content` are ignored.

From [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection)

> The  element is a placeholder that does not create a real DOM element. Custom attributes applied to  are ignored.

So there isn't a specific solution to address this problem. **But fortunately, there is a workaround.**

You can tell Angular to remove the encapsulation for a component by adding inside the `@Component` annotation :

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

This will tell Angular to apply the `some-component.component.scss` to the whole application, instead of the content of `some-component.component.html` only. This will allow your component to apply styles after it's content has been injected inside `<ng-content>`.

Follow this example

**child.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, //Remove css encapsulation
})
```

**child.component.html**

```html
<div id="child">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**child.component.scss**

```css
#child div,
#child app-another-component {
   margin-right: 0.125rem;
}
```

Here, you are free to define any css ruleset and selector you want and suits your needs. To prevent this css from overwriting other component's style, you have to apply an ID to the wrapper and make sure to define CSS rulesets based on the ID. This way, CSS will only apply to your component's content and nowhere else. Be careful to not reuse `id="child"` elsewhere in your app, or theses styles will also be applied.

**parent.component.html**

```html
<app-child>
   <!-- This div will have a margin-right -->
   <div>
      Some content...
   </div>

   <!-- This component will also have a margin-right -->
   <app-another-component></app-another-component>
</app-child>
```

You can try it yourself on [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-haa6wf?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

The elements of ng-content`s are accessible from parent component. i.e. if you write in your app-component.html

```
<content>
     <button class="left">Left</button> 
     <button class="right">Right</button> 
 </content>
```

and you use ng-content in your child component i.e.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Then you can access all of them from your app.component.css i.e.

```
.wrapper button {
 margin:5px 8px 4px 2px;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This is not true. From parent's perspective and due to component encapsulation, what's inside <ng-content> won't be styled by parent's css.